# How to associate an affiliate to a BuyNow purchase

Tags: payment, bluesnap

I'm starting to work with a few affiliates, who will sell my products (from my BlueSnap account) in their websites. They'll manage their online stores as they wish, but when they send to checkout they will use a hosted payment page in an iFrame, and take the URL from me.

I already set up their affiliate account with BlueSnap, and I want to make sure they associate any purchases on their sites so I get a cut and they get their commission. How can I configure the BuyNow URL as associated to a specific affiliate? Is it a setup in the control panel or just a URL parameter?

Is it different for BuyNow 1 and BuyNow2?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In order to make sure your affiliates are getting their cut and that their commissions work you need to make sure that:

- The affiliate account is allowed to sell your products.
- The affiliate is using the right link.

**Managing your Affiliates**

From one of your contracts - at the General settings tab, scroll down to the Marketing section and click the *Invite Partners* link - this will lead you to the Affiliate Management screen where you can make sure that the affiliate account is allowed to sell your goods.

Affiliates that are not on your list, may sell your products, but they will not get any commission.

**Setting up the Affiliate link**

Whether you're using BN1 or BN2 - the link should have the contract (SKU) ID, and the referrer (affiliate) ID:

Example:
https://www.bluesnap.com/jsp/buynow.jsp?contractId=1234567&referrer=123456

I hope this information is useful, by the way - you may want to check our [Marketplace](https://developers.bluesnap.com/docs/marketplace-overview) - if you want to take the affiliating experience to the next level.